# How to disable liquibase.useProcedureSchema

Tags: liquibase

Since upgrading to Liquibase 3.5.1 (from 3.4.2), I have a problem with *createProcedure* and I traced it to [CORE-2626](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2626).

I need to disable **liquibase.useProcedureSchema** but I am unclear on where to specify this.

Comment: nteresting, I was able to find a setter here: github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/… but it is not able to find any place where it is called. As a hack it is possible to change it's default value and rebuild Liquibase, but looks like not a best possible solution.

Comment: I have not tested it myself but I guess it is supposed to be set as a [changelog parameter](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html). Did you try this?